# Module undefined after importing it in a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a function called start to set up my enviroment in python.  The function imports os.
After I run the function and do the following
os.listdir(simdir+"main")
I get a error that says os not defined
code

```
>>> def setup ():
    import os.path
    import shutil
    simdir="e:\\"
    maindir="c:\\backup\\bitcois\\test exit\\"

>>> setup()
>>> os.listdir(simdir+"main")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    os.listdir(simdir+"main")
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Comment: You are inside a function, so there is a local scope in which you can not access the variables.

Comment: Secondly, you would need to `import os` not just `import os.path` to use `listdir`

Answer (score 1):

The `import`  statement is scoped. When importing modules they are defined for the local namespace.

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import):

> Import statements are executed in two steps: (1) find a module, and initialize it if necessary; (2) define a name or names in the local namespace (of the scope where the import statement occurs). [...]

So in your case the `os` package is only defined within function `setup`.

Comment: What about `simdir` that is scoped too?

Comment: Yes, @MalikBrahimi, according variables are local scoped unless a global valiable has been imported using the `global` statement: `"If the name does not occur in a global statement in the current code block: the name is bound to the object in the current local namespace."` ([Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#index-7))

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are NOT importing the whole `os` library but just the `os.path` module. In this way, the other resources at the `os` library are not made available for your use.

In order to be able to use the `os.listdir` method, you need to either import it alongside the `os.path` like this:

```
>>> def setup ():
    import os.path, os.listdir
    import shutil
    simdir="e:\\"
    maindir="c:\\backup\\bitcois\\test exit\\"
```

or import the full library:

```
>>> def setup ():
    import os
    import shutil
    simdir="e:\\"
    maindir="c:\\backup\\bitcois\\test exit\\"
```

You can read more here:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import os.path
import shutil
import glob

def setup ():
    global simdir
    simdir="e:\\"
    maindir="c:\\backup\\bitcois\\test exit\\"

setup()
os.listdir(simdir+"main")
```

Comment: Usage of global ??? Global is bad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the paths and assign the returned values in the global scope. Also, import `os` too:

```
import os

def setup():
    # retain existing code
    return simdir, maindir

simdir, maindir = setup()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import os or do any sort of command within a function, the command's effect only last while that function itself is running. What you need to do is

```
import os
...Do your function and other code
```

This way, your import lasts for the whole program :).